# Requests on a api doesn't work (Curl and python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, curl, python-requests

So, I try to make a program who tell me the schedule of my bus, i take this real time information on an Api:

https://api-lab-trone-stif.opendata.stif.info/service/tr-vianavigo/departures?line_id=100100385%3A385&stop_point_id=StopPoint%3A59%3A6195786

but when i lunch it there is an error :

```
"error": "Unknown dataset: tr-vianavigo"
```

I have a token to use I think but how ? 
the Curl for this api is :

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://api-lab-trone- 
stif.opendata.stif.info/service/tr-vianavigo/departures? 
line_id=100100020%3A20&stop_point_id=59%3A4726914"
```

when i use the first url on my web browser it work and show me :

```
[
  {
    "lineDirection": "Juvisy RER",
    "code": "duration",
    "time": "12"
  },
  {
    "lineDirection": "Savigny Toulouse-Lautrec",
    "code": "duration",
    "time": "20"
  },
  {
    "lineDirection": "Juvisy RER",
    "code": "duration",
    "time": "38"
  },
  {
    "lineDirection": "Savigny Toulouse-Lautrec",
    "code": "duration",
    "time": "45"
  }
]
```

but in python if i just test :

```
import requests 

#my token
apikey = 'ef169369dfd911b01371b73e975ed88adce881bc92dbbd9720551c94'

#url of the api
url ='https://api-lab-trone-stif.opendata.stif.info/service/tr-vianavigo/departures?line_id=100100385%3A385&stop_point_id=StopPoint%3A59%3A6195786'

#requests
r = requests.get(url, apikey)

print(r.text)
```

it make the error :

```
    "error": "Unknown dataset: tr-vianavigo"
```

Comment: when i use the first url on my web browser, it dont work!

Comment: have you logged in before you access url? because i try to read API document but it redirected me to login page.

Comment: Yes i know my friend already tested it but it don't work and yes i'm logged to the main page of the webpage of the api but i don't know how to simulate my log with python, i this is something that you can make with Curl but i don't know how to do it in python 3

Answer (score 0):

You must use one of your API keys for this purpose. An API key is obtained via your user account in [My API keys](https://api-lab-trone-stif.opendata.stif.info/account/api-keys/). Once generated, the key must be inserted as a query parameter (`apikey`) in the URL of your
call. For your example:

```
curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" "https://api-lab-trone-stif.opendata.stif.info/service/tr-vianavigo/departures?line_id=100100020%3A20&stop_point_id=59%3A4726914&apikey=<YOUR-API-KEY>"
```

FYI, the scope of the real-time data available on the dataset `tr-unitaire-stif` is avalaible [here](https://opendata.stif.info/explore/dataset/perimetre-tr-plateforme-stif/information).